# TypeError: Cannot read property 'categories' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, undefined, rendering, typeerror

i'm trying to solve this problem for 2 days but I didn't got the solution till now, can anyone help me,
the categories success rendering in the console and redux normally with the data but not render on the screen

**Category Screen**

```
const category = useSelector(state => state.category);
const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getCategory());
}, [dispatch]);

const renderCategories = (categories) => {
    let myCategories = [];
    for (let category of categories) {
        myCategories.push(
            <li key={category.name}>
                {category.name}
                {/* {category.children.length > 0 ? (<ul>{renderCategories(category.children)}</ul>) : null} */}
            </li>
        );
    }
    return myCategories;
}
```

**the return of this part (the problem is here (Cannot read property 'categories' of undefined)**

```
                <Col md={12}>
                    <ul>
                        {renderCategories(category.categories)}
                    </ul>
                </Col>
```

**Reducer**

```
const initState = {
categories: [],
loading: false,
error: null
```

};

```
export const getCategoryReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case GET_CATEGORY_SUCCESS:
        return { ...state, categories: action.payload.categories };
    default:
        return state;
}
```

};

**the Get Action**

```
export const getCategory = () => {
return async dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: GET_CATEGORY_REQUEST })
    const res = await axios.get(`api/category/getcategory`);
    console.log(res);
    if (res.status === 200) {
        const { categories } = res.data;
        dispatch({ type: GET_CATEGORY_SUCCESS, payload: { categories: categories } })
    } else {
        dispatch({ type: GET_CATEGORY_FAIL, payload: { error: res.data.error } })
    }

}
```

}

**store**

```
    import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { getCategoryReducer } from './reducers/categoryReducers';

import {
    userDeleteReducer,
    userDetailsReducer,
    userListReducer,
    userRegisterReducer,
    userSigninReducer,
    userUpdeteProfileReducer,
    userUpdeteReducer,
} from './reducers/userReducers';

const initialState = {
    userSignin: {
        userInfo: localStorage.getItem('userInfo')
            ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo'))
            : null,
    },
};
const reducer = combineReducers({
    userSignin: userSigninReducer,
    userRegister: userRegisterReducer,
    userDetails: userDetailsReducer,
    userUpdateProfile: userUpdeteProfileReducer,
    userUpdate: userUpdeteReducer,
    userList: userListReducer,
    userDelete: userDeleteReducer,
    getCategory: getCategoryReducer,
});
const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    initialState,
    composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

export default store;
```

**Router in the backend**

```
categoryRouter.get(
'/getcategory',
(req, res) => {
    Category.find({}).exec((error, categories) => {
        if (error) return res.status(400).json({ error });
        if (categories) {
            res.status(200).json({ categories });
        }
    });
});

export default categoryRouter;
```

**category model**

```
   import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
        slug: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
        parentId: { type: String }

    }, { timestamps: true }
);

const Category = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema);

export default Category;
```

Comment: the issue may be here `useSelector(state => state.category);`, because `category` doesn't seem to be defined as part of your state. This may be an issue at the root reducer creation, or you meant `useSelector(state => state.categories);`.

Comment: no the error is not here i tried this too and it overload the errors

Comment: just comment out all your render code that triggers the error (renderCatogories). do `const state = useSelector(state => state)` and console log it to check what you have as state

Comment: you could add your store creation and root reducer to the question, because that's where lies the issue

Comment: i added router and the model now but they are correct i think because i already rendered the categories in the console

Comment: I didn't mean your backend code. You posted your reducer but missed all your reducer and store code

Comment: i don't know what do you mean exactly i updated it again and added all the store file code and the constants only thing i didn't wrote it because it's not important to show for the problem that's it btw
`export const GET_CATEGORY_REQUEST = 'GET_CATEGORY_REQUEST';
export const GET_CATEGORY_SUCCESS = 'GET_CATEGORY_SUCCESS';
export const GET_CATEGORY_FAIL = 'GET_CATEGORY_FAIL';
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here it's the issue:

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
    userSignin: userSigninReducer,
    userRegister: userRegisterReducer,
    userDetails: userDetailsReducer,
    userUpdateProfile: userUpdeteProfileReducer,
    userUpdate: userUpdeteReducer,
    userList: userListReducer,
    userDelete: userDeleteReducer,
    getCategory: getCategoryReducer,
});
```

your combine reducers creates a `getCategory`, not a `category`. In order to proper extract it with `useSelector` you should change it:

```
const category = useSelector(state => state.getCategory);
```

or rename at your combineReducers:

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
    userSignin: userSigninReducer,
    userRegister: userRegisterReducer,
    userDetails: userDetailsReducer,
    userUpdateProfile: userUpdeteProfileReducer,
    userUpdate: userUpdeteReducer,
    userList: userListReducer,
    userDelete: userDeleteReducer,
    category: getCategoryReducer,
});
```

Comment: oh you saved my life man, thanks a lot it solved

Answer (score 0):

`category` can be undefined until the state was full filled. So you can try it this way:

```
{renderCategories(category?.categories)}
```

Comment: `renderCategories` also needs to support null value - right now it will throw an exception.

Comment: it's not worked with me yet after edited to {renderCategories(category?.categories)}, a new error showed (TypeError: categories is not iterable) in this line

for (let category of categories) {
            myCategories.push(
                <li key={category.name}>
                    {category.name}
                </li>

Comment: Because `categories` can be undefined. So you simple add an if before the `for`:
`if(categories) {
for....
}`

Comment: ok i did that and the error gone but nothing rendered it gives me empty <ul>

Comment: Is the api returning data?